# How to make conky auto-hide?

Tags: 12.04, conky, autohide

I think my question is pretty clear. What I want to achieve in conky is auto-hide feature.

The reason for this:

Let's suppose I am browsing and suddenly I want to see my `battery status` or `eth0 downspeed` or `RAM Usage`. Currently what I do is press `Win + D` to show desktop and than see my conky.

Is it possible that I can `hover` my mouse to the top of my screen`(conky align = tm)` and it displays the conky setup.

If it is not possible than is there any other way I can access conky quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of doing this is to cause the action of moving the mouse to the top to show/hide the desktop. Assuming you're using unity, you can do this:

1. Open Ubuntu Software Center. Search for "CompizConfig Settings Manager". Install it.
2. Open CompizConfig Settings Manager and click "General Options".
3. Go to the tab at the top labeled "Key Bindings".
4. Scroll down until you see a screen with the words "Show Desktop" next to it. It should have a button that says "None" across from it.
5. Click that button. A window with a screen in it will pop up. Click the red bar running across that screen. Click OK.
6. If it gives you a pop-up about any other plugin using the top of the screen, click "Set Show Desktop Anyway".

You should now be able to show/hide the desktop by moving the mouse to the top of the screen.

Hope this solves your problem!